# how to sms multi number in android using pendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, sms-gateway

I have problem in my source code, when I SMS multi numbber I just have deliver report which ID same ,it is the last number which was send

```
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI;
    PendingIntent deliverPI;

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content);
        status = json.getString("status");
        message = json.getString("message");
        pesan = json.getString("pesan");
        contacts = json.getJSONArray("contacts");   
        Log.i("INFO","status " + status + ", message " + message + ", pesan "+ pesan + " , jml contacts " + contacts.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject datauser = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("INFO", "no :" + (i + 1) + " " + datauser.getString(NO));

        }

        Intent sendinten = new Intent(SENT);
        Intent deliverIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        int[] id_recever = new Gson().fromJson(id_message, int[].class);

        for (int i = 0; i < id_recever.length; i++) {
            JSONObject datauser = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = String.valueOf(id_recever[i]);

            Log.i("INFO", "ID message " + id);
            deliverIntent.putExtra("id_send", id);

            deliverPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,deliverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,sendinten, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            sms.sendTextMessage(datauser.getString(NO), null, pesan,sentPI, deliverPI);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DATA", "GAGAL");
    }
```

//-----------SMS Delivert -----------//

```
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS send",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("INFO", "SMS SEND");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:// no salah
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: // didn't get service
                                                        // provider
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU: //
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF: // mode airplane
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

//-----------SMS Delivert -----------//

```
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String id_message_send = intent.getStringExtra("id_send");
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Log.i("INFO", "SMS Delivered " + id_message_send);
                AsyncHttpClient postId = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams id = new RequestParams();
                id.put("id_message_send", id_message_send);

                postId.post(URL_UPDATE, id, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onStart();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int arg0, String response) {
                        Log.i("INFO", "Response Server " + response);
                        super.onSuccess(arg0, response);
                    }

                });
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Log.i("INFO", "SMS NOT Deliver");
                break;
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `PendingIntent`s are all unique. Since you are always providing the same ACTION in the `Intent` you pass to `createBroadcast()`, you are always getting the same `PendingIntent` back.

Try setting the `requestCode` parameter to a unique value every time you call `createBroadcast()`, like this (assuming that your `id` parameter is unique):

```
deliverPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), id, deliverIntent, 0);
sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), id, sendinten, 0);
```

Comment: Here for both deliveryPI and sentPi the last parameter 0 indicate which FLAG value ?

Comment: @yousuf The last parameter 0 indicates NO flags are set.